# DB Manager - Oracle DB - Importing vector layer fails prompting "ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier" error

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial, dbmanager

When trying to import a vector layer, to an existing Oracle DB connection, using DB Manager core plugin, the operation fails. An error message prompts with "ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier":
[image]
This happens due to a missing geometry field name parameter in the SQL statement as can be seen in the two adjacent double quotes before the MDSYS part:

```
CREATE TABLE "GIS_WAT_RH"."test"("" MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY)
```

This is puzzling because in the Import vector layer wizard, the geometry column is populated with a geometry field name though grayed out:
[image]

**Why does the geometry field isn't being populated in the DB Manager SQL statement?**

**How to Reproduce**

1. Make an Oracle DB connection via Browser or DB manager
2. Open DB Manager.
3. Navigate to the desired schema inside the previously created Oracle
   connection
4. Import Layer/File...
5. The Import vector layer wizard appears. Input data from a valid
   datasource.
6. Press OK

Comment: I've made a similar [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38268) in QGIS github repository. I'll both platform updated regarding a solution